# How to read specific outlook email using python and save it into excel/csv

Tags: outlook, python-3.6

i am working on a project where i have to read specific outlook email on daily basis.

I receive the certain outlook email on daily basis which looks like a table with the subject : Creation Report - 30/04/2018(these dates change daily)

These are the codes i have found on google:

```
import win32com.client
import os
outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) #Inbox default index value is 6
message=inbox.Items
message2=message.GetLast()
subject=message2.Subject("XID Creation Report")
body=message2.body
date=message2.senton.date()
sender=message2.Sender
attachments=message2.Attachments
print(subject)
print(body)
print(sender)
print(attachments.count)
print(date)
```

can someone please help on this?
Since i dont have much experience in outlook scraping , how can i scrape this subject email from outlook and save it into excel/csv

since body is case sensitive, i cant show it but it is a table.

Comment: What is the output of running `print(dir(message2))`. This should introspect on the available properties and methods on the Item object

Comment: ['_ApplyTypes_', '_FlagAsMethod', '_LazyAddAttr_', '_NewEnum', '_Release_', '__AttrToID__', '__LazyMap__', '__bool__', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattr__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__int__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__]...more to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on my own:

it is simple i am posting my answer here:

```
import win32com.client
import os
outlook=win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNameSpace("MAPI")
inbox=outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6) #Inbox default index value is 6
message=inbox.Items
message2=message.GetLast()
subject=message2.Subject
body=message2.body
date=message2.senton.date()
sender=message2.Sender
attachments=message2.Attachments
for m in message:
    if m.Subject=="Your-subject-here":# here in my requirement i will change the dates
        print(m.body)
```

it will print your body

Comment: But how did you save it on excel/csv?